# Start gnucash specifying with set of books

Tags: gnucash

I have two regularly used gnucash sets of books.  My finances and those of my aged parents.  Is there a command line option by which I can select which set of books open, or am I only limited to the one most recently used, or --nofile?

I'd like two icons, one for each set of books.

Version 4.13 on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the gnucash help text visible by calling "gnucash -h", it shows that the last [optional] command line parameter is a datafile.  Thus you can create two shortcuts, and manually specify the file you would like to load in the parameters of each call.

```
'gnucash file1.gnucash'  << Bookmark1
'gnucash file2.gnucash'  << Bookmark2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the GnuCash app, by default it will open up the last set of books that you previously had open.  Within the app, the *File* menu contains a list of *Most Recently Used* files.  The default is for this list to contain 4 most-recent files (the one that you currently have open, plus up to 3 additional files).

Each set of books is saved in its own data file, of course, with a **.gnucash** suffix.  In your example, those data files will be called something like *MyFinances.gnucash* and *AgedParents.gnucash*.  If you doubleclick either of these datafiles in your file explorer, GnuCash will open and directly load that set of books from the specified data file.

So that's all that you need to do.

If you want to, you can:

1. Create shortcuts to the locations of those data files in your data storage folder, and place those shortcuts on your home desktop for easy access; and
2. Replace the default icon for the shortcut (probably the GnuCash thumbnail icon) with custom icons of your choice.